# SQL запрос к базе Access

Tags: access, delphi, sql

Всем привет. Пишу программу которая парсит некоторые данные с сайта и ищет их в базе Access.

`ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from baza where vopros like' +QuotedStr('%'+Memo1.Text+'%'));
  ADOQuery1.Open;`

В целом нормально работает,но на некоторых вопросах вылезает ошибка:
 "Неправильно определен обьект Parameter. Предоставлены
несогласованные или неполные сведения."

Вот например на таком вопросе ошибка -- Слова: "Я говорю вам: не противься злому. Но кто ударит тебя в правую щеку, то обрати к нему и другую; и кто захочет судиться с тобой и взять и унести твою рубашку, отдай ему и верхнюю одежду" принадлежат

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всегда используйте параметры:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='select * from baza where vopros like :qstr';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('qstr').Value:='%'+Memo1.Text+'%';
```

ЗЫ Ошибка у вас из-за двоеточия в строке.

Comment: спасибо,теперь работает без ошибок!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в quoted string - для кавычек экранирование удвоением.